# OleDB addressing XLS cell position

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am trying to get familiar with OLEDB and I am trying to read a xlsx file with it. However, when I try to read only one cell, I can not address it correctly. In this example I am trying to simply print out first cell (A1) but I am getting B3 cell. What Am I missing?

CODE:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path =@"C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\CLUSTER\FILES\bla.xlsx";
        String connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        OleDbConnection xlConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        xlConn.Open();

        OleDbCommand selectCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [List1$]", xlConn);

        OleDbDataAdapter xlAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        xlAdapter.SelectCommand = selectCmd;
        DataSet xlDataset = new DataSet();
        xlAdapter.Fill(xlDataset, "XLData");

       string variable = xlDataset.Tables[0].Rows[1][1].ToString();

       MessageBox.Show(variable);
    }
```

Can anyone help me? In the next step I would like to read whole xls table with this, so I guess, that I have to set up the range, right? But without knowing how to address cells its difficult.

Comment: Did you tried with `Rows[0][0]`? And are you sure `Rows[1][1]` gets `B3` value? I think it should get `B1`.

Comment: @SonerGönül Since I do not have enough reputation I can not post screenshot of my xls table, but in cell B3 I have value 23 and that is the value I am getting in messagebox. With Rows[0][0] I am getting the A2 cell